# Data Structure: Uniqueness in lists

Tags: java, data-structures

i have 2 lists,one list l1 contains n1 elements and another list l2 contains n2 elements.Both lists are not the same length and contain duplicate elements.I want to create another list which has unique elements from both l1 and l2.How can i do this efficiently and what would be the performance of this solution?

P.S :  i want a solution which does not make use of any other data structures.

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like it.

Comment: Does each list contain possibly duplicate elements or do you only mean there is the possibility of duplication between lists?

Comment: @Cameron : it is a interview question.

Comment: Righto. I've tagged it as such.

Comment: Do you mean 'unique' as in 'elements which are either in l1 or in l2, but not in both'?

Comment: An interesting problem, but if you can't answer it on your own, then perhaps the interview should reflect that.  OTOH, I'm not above hints:  Sorting is your friend.

Comment: @Lars: unique means in l1 or in l2 or in both.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use a Set, I think the best solution is to do a merge-sort with no duplicates. This SO question might help: [How do I use merge sort to delete duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738658/how-do-i-use-merge-sort-to-delete-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Set and add elements from both the Lists l1 and l2. The final set will be the one that contains no duplicates. But make sure you have implemented the equals() and hashCode() correctly.

Below is my sample (not perfect) for doing the same. Posting it here it to validate my logic ;-) or to see if there are better ways of optimizing this

```
Lit unique=...


if(l1.size==l2.size())
{
    //o(n)
    copyToUnique(l1, l2, unique)
}
else if(l1.size>l2.size())
{
    //o(n) + num of extra elements
    copyToUnique(l1, l2, unique)
    unique.addAll(l1.subList(l2.size(),l1.size());
}
else if(l1.size<l2.size())
{
    //o(n) + num of extra elements
    copyToUnique(l2, l1, unique)
    unique.addAll(l2.subList(l1.size(),l2.size());
}

public void copyToUnique(List l1, List l2, List unique)
{
    for(Object element:l1)
    {
        if(!l2.contains(element))
        {
            unique.add(element);
        }
    }
unique.addAll(l2);
}
```

Comment: What if i am not allowed to use any other data structure?

Comment: I am not sure the code will work: if I see this right, it will add the shorter list multiple times to the result (longer list' size times), and it wouldn't remove any duplicates from within the lists. And if l1.size<l2.size() , wouldn't l1.subList(l2.size(),l1.size() be empty/throw an exception?

Comment: Can you explain why 1) it will add the shorter list multiple times to the result  and 2) it wouldn't remove any duplicates from within the lists? I corrected the code so that it doesn't throw exception.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but: 1) copyToUnique() adds all of l2 to unique on every iteration of the for() loop. 2) copyToUnique() only makes sure that l1-elements which are not in l2 are added to unique; but not that the l1 elements themselves are mutually distinct (and ditto for l2). And I'm not sure what the addAll(sublist) on the top level is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: thank you. 1) corrected the code 2) Yes this needs corrections 3) the sublist is the diff(l1,l2) that need to be carry forwarded in case one list is bigger than the other

Comment: I don't think the subList part is needed: the length difference is implicitly handled by the fact that copyToUnique() loops over the one list, and then fully adds the other. In fact, you could drop the if() altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use only lists, and you have the possibility of duplicates both within each list AND across lists, then you need to create a new list, l3 (to hold the union of l1 and l2 elements) and iterate through each list, doing an insert of each element e item if a call to l3.contains(e) returns false.

As others have mentioned, using a Set is definitely the easiest way to remove duplicate items of a list, and a List can be created from the Set to return to the caller.

The performance is linear and based on the number of elements in l1 + l2.

Comment: performance of this isn't linear, it's O(n^2), or something like that.  You have to consider the check of whether the third list contains the element already.

Comment: That doesn't make it O(n^2).  It really depends on the List implementation that is used, but a worst case contains implementation from the SDK will be linear I believe (ArrayList) and the insert will be a worst case linear.  So, even though it's not a straight O(n), there's a multiplier there and linear growth, NOT an exponent and quadratic growth.

Comment: Depends on whether l3 is sorted or not. If not sorted, and assuming the worst case of no duplicates, l3.contains() will be executed on a list of increasing size, executing from 0 comparisons at the start to N=(l1+l2-1) comparisons at the end : sum(0 .. N) = N * (N-1) / 2 .

Answer (score 0):

A solution that's O(nlogn) would be to sort each list, then walk through both lists together, finding duplicates.  You would increment the position of one list or the other list (or both) depending on which list has the "smallest" value of the current element (or if they're the same).  There's a reasonable bit of overhead, so some O(n^2) algorithms could actually could be faster depending on the size/distribution of the data.