# What C library is best for single char keys appending values to an int array?

Tags: c, arrays, hashmap

What C hash table library would be best for single char keys and values as int arrays? [This link](http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html) says Glib is great for plain C applications.

I'm a C newbie but am familiar with Python. I've profiled an algorithm in Python and have seen over 75% time spent converting a list to a dictionary.

I'm looking for a high performance C hash table to replace the Python algorithm.

These 3 steps will be run from a few thousand to a few million times. It was suggested I use linked lists but, I want to try a hash table as well in the case I have runs of data with as few as 4 chars in a linked list of length 256.

1. The Python list is in the form
    `[[char, int], [char, int], ...]`
2. The list will be converted into a dictionary/hash table in the form
    `{char: [int, int, int, ...], char: ...}`
3. The desired output is a sorted list/array of chars with corresponding int arrays
    `[['a', [1,2,3,67,83,90]], [['g', [300000, 300001]], ...]`
4. Chars may be duplicate however, ints are all unique.

This isn't homework. I'm a biologist trying to work with my own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about libraries that have this specific case handled already, but a solution would be quite simple in this case.

Since chars are usually 8 bit, you only have 2^^8 = 256 entries (which is not very many, and guarantees no collisions), so I would have a 2 dimensional array and use unsigned chars to index the array.  Or, to make it more dynamic have an array of linked lists.  You could use a Merge Sort on the linked lists. You could also write your own integer linked list to make it easier to handle.

Here is a short, simple example that allows duplicates. (I missed that part when I wrote this up). *Credit to [this helpful example](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml) for a quick and dirty integer comparator function)*

To ignore duplicates, you can replace `qsort()` with a merge sort that [removes duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738658/how-do-i-use-merge-sort-to-delete-duplicates).

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // qsort(), rand()
#include <time.h>   // time(NULL)
#include <ctype.h>  // isprint()


//The hashmap.
int map[256][1000];
// the size of values stored in each array.
int size[256];

// put a value in the array.
void put(unsigned char c, int n)
{
    map[c][size[c]] = n;
    size[c] += 1;
}

// for qsort.
int comparator(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    const int *i1 = (const int *)p1;
    const int *i2 = (const int *)p2;
    return *i1  - *i2;
}

// for printing the data.
void print_all_data()
{
    int row;
    for(row = 0; row < 256; row ++)
    {
        // skip empty rows.
        if (size[row] == 0) continue;

        // first, sort the row.
        qsort(map[row], sizeof(int), size[row], &comparator);

        // then, print it.
        printf("['%c', [", row);
        for(int i = 0; i < size[row]; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", map[row][i]);
            if(i != size[row] - 1)
             printf(",");
        }
        printf("]]\n");
    }
}


// run the example.
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", i);
        unsigned char c = rand() % 256;
        int i = rand() % 1000;

        // only use printable chars.
        if (isprint(c))
            put(c, i);
    }
    print_all_data();
}
```

Comment: I will definitely try that! I should have added that steps 1-3 will be run thousands of times. I'm concerned that iterating over empty lists will be more expensive than a hash table if the data ratio shifts from many chars to few chars. I should try the hash table in addition to your suggestion.

Comment: I could write up some examples if you want, it is an interesting idea.  It would likely be far more efficient to treat each entry as an array (over a linked list) and insert as a stack, reallocating more memory as necessary.  That way you can use the library sort function from stdlib on your arrays and not have to write more custom code.  It is a good opportunity to learn more about c, in any case you have to `malloc()` and `realloc()` if you go with the array idea.

Comment: A simple example would be helpful. I'm not sure if my data structure should be in the stack or the heap for thousands-millions of ints sorted by 3-256 different chars.

Comment: @mattkaeo Any performance problems you might have will come from how you insert into the `int` arrays. The outer array that's indexed by `char` will be very efficient.

Comment: @Barmar I'm surprised that adding to the array is the expensive part. Is this at all related to this YouTube video ["Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) meaning C has limitations here. Or, should I seek out additional resources for adding to my array more efficiently?

Comment: Also, if you feel like you know the upper bound of how many values you want to store in one run.  For instance, a statically declared 2D integer array  of size 256 x 10,000 only requires ~9.8 MB of space.  I'll write up a simple example using arrays and add it to my answer relatively soon.

Comment: @mattkaeo I assumed you want to prevent duplicates, so the expensive part is searching the array to see if the integer is already in the list. If not, then adding to the array should also be efficient. In any case, my main point is that there's no need to hash the chars, a simple array of 256 pointers to the lists will be fine.

Comment: The other expensive part is keeping the integer lists sorted.

Comment: @Barmar I added that ints are unique in the question. Sorting seems to be an unavoidable problem. I'm assuming that the benefit of using C over Python for converting my data will be greater than the benefit of using Timsort in Python over the standard sort in C. My ints are partially sorted so maybe a Timsort library will become helpful.

Comment: Well, I added some example code that allows duplicates, maybe give you an idea of how I'd approach it.

Comment: Also, see my added link on merge sorts that throws away duplicate values, that may exactly what you may need.