# Remove duplicate array elements with O(nlogn) using merge sort

Tags: c#

Can I remove duplicate array elements with O(nlogn) by using merge sort?

**Example:**

Input Array:

```
[1,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,6,6]
```

Expected Array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Please show how you have tried to do this in this complexity. What is the closest you have got

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738658/how-do-i-use-merge-sort-to-delete-duplicates

Comment: I do not want to use ready class

Comment: A merge sort is a *sorting* algorithm that uses the divide and conquer strategy. Of course you can use it to remove duplicates by simply not merging them.

Answer (score -2):

```
int[] expectedArray = inputArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```